# CSS selectors inside ul li

Tags: html, css

I have a ul/li menu that I'm trying to add `:hover` and `:focus` attributes to:

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="/page1">Item 1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="/page2">Item 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/page3">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <span class="mobile-hidden">Item 3</span>
      <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/page4">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <span class="mobile-hidden">Item 4</span>
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So using the following CSS I'm able to grab the first 2 items, but nothing of the latter 2. Adding additional selectors for the `<span>` and `<li>` tags doesn't seem to work.

```
ul li:hover, ul li:focus{
  color: #0077ff;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you grab `<ul>` & `<li>` that's good. The problem is your `<i>` and `<span>` tags are inside a `<a>` tag. In these cases, the `<a>` styling always comes before its content.

So you'll have to make somthing like this :

```
ul li:hover a, ul li:focus a{
  color: #0077ff;
}
```

Comment: Two things: a) it should be `ul li a:hover`. b) Even using `ul li a:hover` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer:

```css
ul li:hover a, ul li:focus a{

  color: #0077ff;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="/page1">Item 1</a></li>
  <li> <a href="/page2">Item 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/page3">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <span class="mobile-hidden">Item 3</span>
      <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/page4">
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <span class="mobile-hidden">Item 4</span>
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This code will have the following effect.

```
ul li:hover, ul li:focus{
  color: #0077ff;
}
```

The `<a>` tags will take up the space inside the `<li>`  tags. Therefore when you put your mouse on the `<li>`. Therefore your mouse won't actually be on an `<li>` tag but on an `<a>` tag and thus the css rules won't work.